# virtual inheritance in the non-diamond inheritance tree - memory & behavior side-effects

Tags: c++, abi, virtual-inheritance, memory-layout

I understand the **effect** of *virtual inheritance* in diamond inheritance tree but not the side-effects (if any) in a non-diamond inheritance tree.

If you just have

```
class A;

class B: public virtual A;
```

What differences are there in **behavior** or **memory layout** (if any) of these two classes i.e. order of constructor calls, etc.

Assume `class A` has data members.

***Please provide official documentation for your answer***

Comment: It works the same way if you have a diamond or not.

Comment: I doubt the standard will mandate the implementation detail. AFAIK, you don't even need to use a vtable (although most do).

Comment: @NathanOliver what's the behavior in my example?

Comment: @Adrian You might want to elaborate what you consider *behavior*. I think you can ask yourself what the *behavior* is when you don't use `virtual` inheritance (I am sure it's absolutely clear to you), and from the answer to this question you can define what you consider *behavior*. Then [edit] your question to clarify that.

Comment: I don't believe the memory layout is specified. The behavior in a non-diamond case is not changed (except possibly minor performance implications), just as making a method virtual without overriding it changes no behaviors (but can be a tiny bit slower).  If you want official documentation, that would be the C++ spec; so why ask for it here?

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't say anything about memory layout. You may want to check the description of the compiler ABI.

Answer (score 2):

One effect of virtual inheritance is that downcasting by `static_cast` doesn't work. If you want to downcast from a virtual base, you must use `dynamic_cast` instead.

```
A* pa = new B;
B* pb1 = static_cast<B*>(pa); // doesn't work: compilation error
B* pb2 = dynamic_cast<B*>(pa); // works
```

Quoted from Standard (5.2.9):

> A prvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B,” where B is a class type, can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to cv2 D,” ... if ... B
>   is neither a virtual base class of D nor a base class of a virtual base class of D.

Comment: Yes! This is the kind of info I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the memory layout, some compilers might place the virtual base's data members **after** the subclass's data members (see [Multiple Inheritance Considered Useful](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/multiple-inheritance-considered-useful/184402074)):

```
class A {
public:
    int a;
};

class B : public virtual A {
public:
    int b;
};

int main() {
    B b;

    std::cout << "&b.a < &b.b = " << (&(b.a) < &(b.b)) << std::endl; // &b.a < &b.b =  = 0

    return 0;
}
```

On the other hand, non-virtual base's data members are usually placed **before** the child's data members:

```
class A {
public:
    int a;
};

class B : public virtual A {
public:
    int b;
};

int main() {
    B b;

    std::cout << "&b.a < &b.b = " << (&(b.a) < &(b.b)) << std::endl; // &b.a < &b.b = 1

    return 0;
}
```